# Can't get JOptionPane and System.out.println to work in tuition calculator

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Tuition
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //Declareing the variables
        int credits;
        double costPerCredit;
        double tuition;

        //calling methods
        credits = getCredits();
        costPerCredit = getCostPerCredit(credits);
        tuition = calcTuition(credits, costPerCredit);
        displayCredits(costPerCredit);
        displayTotal(tuition);


        //Dialog box that is popping out to ask the questions and get imput based on questions
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Java Tuition Calculator Program");
    }

    public static int getCredits()
    {
        //declare hours variable
        String input;
        int credits = 0;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number of Credits?");

        return credits;
    }

    public static double getCostPerCredit(int credits)
    {
        String input1;
        double costPerCredit;
        costPerCredit = credits * 107.78;
        input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Cost Per Credit?");

        return costPerCredit;
    }

    public static double calcTuition(int credits, double costPerCredit)
    {
        double tuition;

        tuition = credits * costPerCredit;
        return tuition;
    }


    public static void displayCredits(double costPerCredit)
    {
        double credits;
        credits = costPerCredit;

        DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("$#000.00");
        System.out.println("Cost for Credits are " + credits);
    }

    public static void displayTotal(double tuition) 
    {
        double total;
        total = tuition;

        DecimalFormat twoDigits = new DecimalFormat("$#000.00");
        System.out.println("Your Tuition is " + total);
    }
}
```

When I execute the code it should ask me to type the number of credits I am currently going to take and cost per credit. After I input those the total result should come up in a new window with the phrase "Cost for credits are *(the answer should come out from the equation "tuition = credits * costPerCredit;")*. That number result should be the number I put in the first dialog box multiping with the pre-set $107.78, and I want those answers to be in the new window that pops out in the end. But all i get is

```
Cost for Credits are 0.0
Your Tuition is 0.0
```

Why can't I get System.out.println to print out the answer from `public static double getCostPerCredit(int credits)` and `public static int getCredits()`? The dialog box pops up for both of them and asks the questions in the field but I want those answers to be printed out and not just result in the answer being "0.0".

Note: I took out `String input1;` and `input1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Cost Per Credit?");`. The code seems to work the same way w/o it but the dialog box is removed.

Comment: It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with a more specific question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can't get JOptionPane and System.out.println to work in tuition
>   calculator
>
> ```
> First: Cost for Credits are 0.0 because of int credits = 0; and you return credits 0 as type int
>
> Second: Any thing multiply by 0.0 is 0.0 as type double, So Your Tuition is 0.0
> ```

```
public static int getCredits()
    {
        //declare hours variable
        String input;
        int credits = 0;
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number of Credits?");

        return Integer.parseInt(input);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, John Kugelman and Soumya Das for your help, very much appreciated. Thank you again :D

Answer (score 0):

```
String input;
int credits = 0;
input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Number of Credits?");

return credits;
```

`credits` is never changed. This code always returns `0`.